# Sort, group and calculate average in csv python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, average

I have a large 4 column csv file, with random values and I need to group the rows by a specific column ID and then average the coordonates in another file. Also, I would like to keep the number of decimals.

```
ID, Latitude, Longitude, Cluster
1, 22.29124068, 19.59633257, 500
2, 22.28295135, 19.85912179, 214
3, 22.30154457, 19.65304535, 500
4, 22.29546953, 19.76508808, 214
5, 22.3322929, 19.75290081, 422
etc...
```

So what I need to do is calculate the average coordinate from col[1] and col[2] for each unique cluster col[3] in that file and return the results.

The output file should be:

```
ID, Latitude, Longitude, Cluster
1, <average_latitude_214 cluster>, <average_longitude_214 cluster>, 214
1, <average_latitude_500 cluster>, <average_longitude_500 cluster>, 500
and so on...
```

Comment: Awesome .. start coding. Come back if you encounter problems. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickArtner ! I managed to sort the data, but I cannot find examples on how to average data for each cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using a 3rd party library, you can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

# read csv file
df = pd.read_csv('file_in.csv')

# perform groupby
res = df.groupby('Cluster')[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].mean().reset_index()

print(res)

#    Cluster   Latitude  Longitude
# 0      214  22.289210  19.812105
# 1      422  22.332293  19.752901
# 2      500  22.296393  19.624689

# write to csv
res.to_csv('file_out.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's `defaultdict` to create a list of all entries with the same cluster. From that you can then calculate an average for each cluster and write the row into your output CSV file:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        row[1] = float(row[1])
        row[2] = float(row[2])
        data[row[3]].append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:        
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for id, (cluster, items) in enumerate(sorted(data.items()), start=1):
        latitude = sum(i[1] for i in items) / len(items)
        longitude = sum(i[2] for i in items) / len(items)

        csv_output.writerow([id, latitude, longitude, cluster])
```

This would create an `output.csv` file containing:

```
ID,Latitude,Longitude,Cluster
1,22.289210439999998,19.812104935,214
2,22.3322929,19.75290081,422
3,22.296392625000003,19.62468896,500
```